# unable to fetch the latest version code from firebase

Tags: java, android

here I'm fetching the latest version of my app from firebase but after updating the value in console this code is not reflecting updated value of my version pls tell  me where i'm going wrong

```
  FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
                //This is default Map
                firebaseDefaultMap = new HashMap<>();
                //Setting the Default Map Value with the current version code
                firebaseDefaultMap.put(VERSION_CODE_KEY, getCurrentVersionCode());
    
                //Setting that default Map to Firebase Remote Config
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(firebaseDefaultMap);
    
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(
                        new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                                .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(0)
                                .build());
```

here I'm fetching version from firebase remote config

```
 mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //activate most recently fetch config value
                            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activate().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        //calling function to check if new version is available or not
                                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                                        final double latestAppVersion =  mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getDouble(VERSION_CODE_KEY);
                                        Log.d("appversionlatest",String.valueOf(latestAppVersion));
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                checkForUpdate();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try{
        String versionName = getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit**

```
import <your package name>.BuildConfig;

String verName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

also, you will get

```
.DEBUG 
.APPLICATION_ID 
.BUILD_TYPE 
.VERSION_CODE
```

**These ara present in gradle.build**

```
defaultConfig {
   minSdkVersion 21
   targetSdkVersion 30
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"....
```

Comment: can u tell me that where i need to add this code

Comment: I want that when I change the current version of my app in firebase then latestversion should be as same as version updated but this code is showing prev version of our app

Comment: This value fetching from ```gradle.build```

Comment: see my ```Edit```

Comment: firebase which I've changed in remote config section of consol in firebase

Comment: and your this code will give me the current version from gradle.build

Comment: I`ll have another way, store value in ```Firebase Database``` then fetch data to display your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234106/discussion-between-ganesh-mb-and-yash-gupta).